# Exception Handling regarding nesting of try

Tags: c#

This was the objective type question which was asked me in one of my interview that .. Can we have try inside the try block? I think the answer is no. But I have to confirm the answer. So please tell me the correct answer.

Comment: There's a very, very easy way of confirming whether `try` blocks can be nested: try it for yourself.

Comment: Cut to the chase: yes, they can be nested. Whether they SHOULD be nested is another question. Occasionally, there is reason for that, especially if you wish to catch specific exceptions (essentially ignoring them) and moving on. Not something I'd write myself, but I've seen it done. Primarily opinion based here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a common practice; here is a simple example:

```
try {
  string source = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\source.txt");

  string result = DoSomething(source);

  try {
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\target.txt", result);
  }
  catch (IOException eTarget) {
    //  Can't write into target
    ...
  }  
}
catch (IOException eSource) {
  // Can't read from source  
  ... 

  try {
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Log.err", "Failed to read the source: " + e.Message);
  }
  catch (IOException eLog) {
    // Can't write to log
    ...   
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: yes, you can. Moreover you can also put try inside catch block. The .net compiler would not complain about that.